# how to select only one particular field from model in zend framework

Tags: zend-db-table

How to select only one field from table inside a model. 
For example: `table1(field1, field2 , ..)` and the `select only field 1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want only one value or a rowset with one column?

In first case, you can use fetchOne():

**$result = $db->fetchOne('SELECT bug_status FROM bugs WHERE bug_id = 2');**

Or you can make a select only with the fields you want to retreive:

**$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('t' => 'table1'),
                    array('field1'));**

Comment: I mean from Model file of the framework. if i try this code in model then i get the error ,,,,cannot join this table to that table. Please could you help me in the MODEL file. I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: what is t in first array?